# How do I search a Large IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Collection Based on the Sum of the Inner IEnumerable Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, bigdata

I have a dataset with ~400 items in it. Using a recursive method I calculate the number of different combinations there are of picking a subset of size n. For example if the collection was {1,2,3,4,5} and n=3 then I would select all the different combinations of picking 3 items from the list. This results in a collection of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` where the size is calculated as follows n! / ( k! * (n - k)! ) where n=the number of items to pick and k is the size of the original collection. As you can see this number gets very large!

What I want to be able to do with this dataset is select the combinations based upon the sum of the inner collection e.g using the above collection if I wanted to only select results where the sum of the inner collection was 6 for example I would expect to get the collection which contained 1,2,3 since 1+2+3=6. Iterating over the resulting collection is not a feasible solution due to it's size.

I've been thinking of trying to do some kind of quicksort and then using a binary search to select the possible combinations but I'm not sure how to go about doing this in code, whether or not it's feasible or if it's the best way to go about solving this kind of problem.

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem you were trying to solve initially? Because with this formulation, it seems there is no solution. But it seems to me you were trying to find for some dataset if there was some subset of it that has a specific sum, and this problem has a known solution (it is known as the subset sum problem).

Comment: The original problem was: You have an end of football league table, how do you determine the minimum number of games you would need to remove for any team to win the league? For example, if team A finished top of the league, 2 points above team B then we could remove any of team As wins for team B to win the league. This is easy for the first case but once you get to the bottom of the league you get lots of different combinations and iterating all of those and applying those to a league table is not feasible.

Comment: Do you have the results of all games or just the total points for each team?

Comment: I have the results for all the games too.

Comment: Any ideas @JuanLopes?

Comment: Is this more than an academic exercise? I mean, what's the use of a statement "team M would have won if matches x, y, and z wouldn't have been played"? Next season they're going to be played again, no matter what. I think it's meaningless information. Anyway, maybe you can reverse the strategy: one-by-one remove matches from all matches and each time calculate which team would have ended as top team in *that* set of matches. Then collect all winning match lists per team.